# Access dataItem inside transport.read function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-datasource

This question is a mirror from [this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/access-dataitem-inside-transport-read-function) on Telerik's Forum that I have posted yesterday.

I have a TreeView with HierarchicalDataSource and my question is simple: Can I access the current dataItem in the transport.read function?

For instance, consider this code:

```
new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            // Here i'll prepare my url to be called
            return "my/controller/" + dataItem.Id;
        }
    }
});
```

I want to access the dataItem's properties of the current expanding node inside the read function. Is this possible?

I have tried many ways but the scope inside that function gives me access of nothing outside it.

**UPDATE**:

@OnaBai suggestion worked with - in my case - `Value` property, given the following model:

```
{
    id: "Value",
    hasChildren: "HasChildren"
};
```

But I want to be able to access more that just `Id` but the entire `dataItem`. I've tried to add dataItem's - or request - properties to the model but it doesn't worked:

```
{
    id: "Value",
    hasChildren: "HasChildren",
    fields: {
        ParentId: { type: "string" }
    }
};
```

`ParentId` comes from the resquest and its accesible in `dataItem`, but not in `options` inside `read` function. There's another way to do that ?

**UPDATE 2**:

A tricky way of doing this can be achieved by setting the model's id to `uid`:

```
{
    id: "uid"
}
```

The function will receive the uid and then you can get it from dataSource with, e.g. `dataSource.getByUid()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Id` the `id` defined in your model, you should do:

```
new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            return "my/controller/" + options.Id;
        }
    }
});
```

See an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mE4zZ/2/

**EDIT**: If you need to access the full model then known the `id` you can use `get` method on the DataSource for getting the item.

Example:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            if (options.Id) {
                var item = ds.get(options.Id);
                // Do whatever else you need with Item
            }
            return "my/controller/" + options.Id;
        }
    }
});
```

Modified JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mE4zZ/3/

Comment: Thank you. I worked, but I still don't get the full dataItem. Please see my update. Thank you again.

Comment: Check the **EDIT** for getting all the item